# How pass HttpClient response with web api response in asp.net core

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core

I have a Rest API project that was written in asp.net core 3.1. In this project, I have some data from internal service that is simple and some remote data that comes from remote API.

The response type of remote API is JSON, and I prefer don't cast the response to an object. I don't want the API project depends on remote API object structure type, only get data and pass that data as JSON format to the API client.

How can I combine these data as the response of API?

```
public class VideoDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

REST API

```
private readonly IVideoQueryManager _videoQueryManager;

public async Task<ActionResult<object>> Get(int id)
{
    var videoDto = await _videoQueryManager.Get(id)

    using var client = new HttpClient();

    var response = await client.GetAsync($"http://example.com/videos/{id}/commments");

    string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return new
    {
        videoDto = videoDto,
        comments = //How set responseBody here???
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what's returned by your API, doesn't it?

- If it's a straight string, you can use `GetStringAsync` instead and get a straight string from the response.
- If it's a JSON object, you can decode it with a JSON parser and extract the correct field.

As a side note, you should be returning `IAsyncResult` in modern ASP.NET MVC Core, your return type is the old return type -- note in particular that the `object` is useless, since you're not defining your return type specifically at all.

Comment: Also since you have 2 independent queries, you should be running them at the same time, not sequentially like you are in your code.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I edit to my question to clarify what I want

Comment: If you're asking how to deserialize a JSON string and extract data from it, one way is to use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>` after you define the structure of the JSON response returned by your API.

Comment: I don't want to deserialize to an object, because the response is a complex type and I don't define a complex type in this context

Comment: But you still need to extract data from that "complex" format, so you either define a type that contains the structure of the data you receive, or you use the form without a type that returns an `object` and cast it to `dynamic`, or you parse it as a `JToken` or `JArray` or whatever your data is and access it through the provided indexers.

Comment: I don't want to create a complex object, I query for a generic solution, do you have any idea?

Comment: I don't know what "complex" and "generic" means in this case, you're querying a particular API which gives you a particular response. You can argue with the API provider if you think it's too complex, you're wasting both my time and yours right now.

Comment: I didn't want to west your time, I'm sorry. I mean, I don't want the API project depends on remote API response type, only get data and pass to the client.

Answer (score 0):

An API is an application programming *interface*. In other words, the object structures returned function just as an code-based interface would. As such, you can and *should* have a class in the client application that "implements" the interface, giving you something to bind the data to.

From the APIs perspective, just as a code-based interface should not change once published, neither should the data structure returned by the API. If changes are required, a new version needs to be published, and then any clients should be given a deprecation warning and prompted to update their code to accommodate those changes *before* they actually take permanent effect. You then, as the consumer of the API would simply change your class to match the new version.

Long and short, just create a class to represent the data and deserialize into that. This is how it works, and there's nothing wrong with doing that.